# bloquear acesso a uma pagina apenas com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, login

tenho um arquivo index.html, que após login é direcionado para uma pagina chamada home.html

existe alguma forma de bloquear o acesso direto a essa home.html apenas com javascript?

Comment: Não é possível. Todo bloqueio de acesso realizado no código cliente pode ser contornado pelo usuário usando as ferramentas desenvolvimento incluídas no navegador, faça esse bloqueio de acesso no servidor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um controle usando sessionStorage.

Em index.html:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('usuarioLogado', '1');
```

Em home.html:

```
var usuarioLogado = sessionStorage.getItem('usuarioLogado');

if (!usuarioLogado) {
    window.location = "ENDEREÇO PARA ONDE VOCÊ QUER REDIRECIONAR"
}
```

Comment: Obs: [sessionStorage][https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage] é limpo após fechar o navegador. Caso queira que dique salvo após isso, você deve usar [localStorage][https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage].

Comment: consegui usando  isso + o new Date do javascript.